# HttpClient 4.3.3 on Android

Tags: android, apache, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I cannot use httpclient 4.3.3 libraries on Android. I tried to add jar files to libs folder but it still uses its own httpclient packages. They have both same package names. I think this is the problem.

Is there any solution for that?

Comment: you can delete old imports and use your own HttpClient 4.3.3 imports

Comment: @MurtazaHussain: No, you cannot. The firmware always wins; Android will use Android's version of the HttpClient classes, not the one in app-supplied JAR.

Comment: Yes you can. If you import your libraries system will use yours. I hope classes are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using the [official Apache HttpClient 4.3 Android port](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html)

Answer (score 2):

> I think this is the problem.

Yes, it is.

> Is there any solution for that?

Use `HttpUrlConnection`. Or use `OkHttp`. Or see if `jarjar` can handle refactoring a library as large as HttpClient to a new package.